# Scraping a web page: Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, scraper

I want to extract some data from an HTML page.

I tried it with php, but I got an issue because this page is only available if you are connected to a specific network: unfortunately, my client is connected to that network, but not my server, so php requests fail.

My question is: if I try to scrape the page with javascript instead of php, will my request seem to come from my client network?

Comment: `scrape the page with javascript` Not possible unless the remote page allows remote connections. If it does, then the request will be from your clients.

Comment: @DaveChen why is it not possible with javascript?

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Comment: @DaveChen you also check out https://github.com/tautologistics/node-htmlparser/

Comment: it's easy with javascript, as long as you can see the info on the page, javascript can send that info somewhere else, like a file. Tampermonkey is the best scraping platform around these days. all you need to do is create a new userscript for the site/page, and in that script grab the innerHTML(s) and download it to a file or push it to another url waiting to capture the data into something like a DB.

Answer (score 0):

No it won't, unless you execute it in a browser which is already on your clients network! What you should checkout perhaps is a proxy or a VPN. Route your servers traffic through your clients network, this way it will appear to be coming from there IP address.

Comment: Yes, the page with javascript source will be located on my server, but it's executed in a browser which is already on my clients network. 
Will it appear to be coming from which ip addr?